# Asp.NET Core Kestrel not using host configuration file

Tags: asp.net-core, multi-tenant, kestrel-http-server

I have an Asp.NET Core project that is intended to be a multi-tenant application, but I'm having trouble configuring the project to use the host names I define in a hosting.json file.  It works fine if I use UseUrls(), but I eventually need these settings for localhost to be able to be overwritten by environment variables.  This is what's going on in my main thread:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    //.UseApplicationInsights()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

And my hosting.json file:

```
{
  "server.urls": "http://localhost:5000;http://localhost:5001"
}
```

If I start the project, it only listens on the App Url defined in the debug section of project properties.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.

I used [this tutorial](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core/) to get to this point.

Comment: The url only works when you host ASP.NET Core project in a console application (via Kestrel), not when you run it in IIS or IISExpress. In later case (IISExpress), it reads it from the .vs/config/applicationhost.config in your solution folder

Comment: I am running it in a console application, not IIS.

Comment: Do you copy over the hosting.json to your build directory via `<Content Update="wwwroot;Views;web.config;hosting.json;appsettings**.json">` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Inside your project's csproj (or `"buildOptions" { "copyToToOutput" : [ ...] }` in project.json). By default inside the solution are not copied over to the build (bin/debug/xxx) directory. But when your application runs it searches it there. So you need to add instructions to the build pipeline to copy this file there.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in the csproj file.  How do I change the build pipeline?